# Send Json to PHP and empty $_POST

Tags: php

Due to this problem I have summarized the error in the most basic example to find a solution.
I have a PHP file with the following code:

```
if( isset($_POST['nombre']) ){
        echo("Do thing");
   }
else{
    echo("Error");
}
```

If I send the **NAME** data from a post form, it enters the **IF** without problem.
If from Postman I try to send a data from *BODY FORM-DATA* or *x-www.form.urlencoded*, the POST arrives without problem and enters the IF.

```
{"nombre": "fdsf"}
```

But if I send a JSON from postman, something like $_POST['name'] comes back empty and being empty does not enter the **IF**

Does anyone know why it happens?.

Comment: Why `$_POST['name']` when key is `nombre`?

Comment: _"Does anyone know why it happens?"_ - anyone who bothers to read up on things in the manual - https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 'php://input'
It allows us to read raw data from the request body, regardless of the content type.
Try this

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $data = json_decode($json);

        return print_r($data);
```